# question on tomcat and jmx

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, tomcat, jmx

What is the `MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null);` exactly doing?
Returns a list of all registered MBeanServers? Registered where?
I am asking because I have the following problem.
I have a java web app deployed in Tomcat using a service wrapper.
I have custom connector implementations in my server.xml that use ManagedBeans (spring enabled).
If I start the app via the service wrapper all is ok.
If I start the web app through Tomcat directly it seems that the deployment breaks.
All I see in the logs is that the connector does a

```
MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null);
```

and then tries to invoke the bean `beanServer.invoke(name, operationName, null, null);`
The result is a InstanceNotFoundException.
It seems that the managed beans are not loaded in case I do not use a service wrapper? Is my understanding correct? Any input on how to debug this issue is 
highly welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/management/MBeanServerFactory.html#findMBeanServer%28java.lang.String%29) says that when you pass `null`, it returns the servers registered in the current JVM. If you are using JSW, then you cannot use `null` as JSW forks the VM as a separate process. This is why you see the `InstanceNotFoundException`.

Comment: @lobster:When you say JSW you mean service wrapper?Using service wrapper, as I mention in post, it works fine.If I start directly via Tomcat I get the exception

Comment: Yeah, Java Service Wrapper. Why do you need a service wrapper when you're deploying in Tomcat? Tomcat itself uses a service wrapper. Sorry this is not helping your question but maybe we can figure something out.

Comment: The specific wrapper used has lot's of extra features.There is no `InstanceNotFoundException` deployed like that.The configuration of the wrapper starts the jvm with `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` and also the option to use a mbeans is enabled in JSW configuration. I am not sure if something is missing if I deploy directly from Tomcat

Comment: You need to add the -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote line to your catalina.sh when you start tomcat standalone - I assume you're doing catalina.sh start or catalina.sh run. Add it to JAVA_OPTS line at the very end.

Comment: @lobster:Ok I will check this out.Is this enough or is any other configuration for Tomcat MBean server needed? For JSW I enable the `Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` but I also set another configuration for MBean as specified.Anything extra for Tomcat MBean server?

Comment: This should be all you need, it will start with default ports etc and SSL auth etc. Try to copy all the jmx settings you see in JSW into catalina.sh and you'd be fine. Best of luck!

Comment: @lobster:After looking into this, the problem I had was related to a firewall.For somereason even though my application did not enable JMX, JMX was already enabled. I suspect because of another application running in the same container.I will create a new thread for this.+1 for your help.

Comment: @lobster:New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764429/question-on-web-app-deployment-in-tomcat