# Web app deployment in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jmx

Does Tomcat use a different Java Virtual Machine (JVM) for each web application running in its container, or does all web applications in Tomcat run under the same JVM?

So for a specific example: if a web application under webapps, enables JMX programmatically (via System properties) does this mean that JMX is enabled for all web applications running in the container?

I believe this is the case, but would like to confirm.

This question came up from my problem in this thread: [question on tomcat and jmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736332/question-on-tomcat-and-jmx/5736413#comment-6565323). Any input on the subject is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tomcat runs in a single JVM, so every app deployed to a single tomcat instance runs in the same VM as every other application. They get different classloaders, so they're isolated from each other in that sense, but the JVM is the same.

So any feature enabled JVM-wide will be enabled for every application in that instance.

Comment: @Joseph:Is there a case that 2 different apps will use the same classloaders?

Comment: I don't know that there's a normal case where that happens - that'd violate the Java EE specification rather badly, but that doesn't prevent inventive programmers from going out of their way to screw things up. But Tomcat by itself doesn't use the same classloader for more than one web application, although web applications will share *parent* classloaders, obviously.

Comment: Tomcat uses a hierarchy of classloaders: bootstrap, server, and application.  Every application gets their own classloader, but they share the higher ones.

Comment: Joseph Ottinger is spot on with his answer, by the way.  I'd accept it.

Comment: Please also note that you should not rely on observed behaviour for Tomcat but defined behaviour for the servlet container according to the specification.

Comment: @ Thorbjørn:I see what you mean.I have an issue relating to class loading in Tomcat.I will use a different thread for this.

Comment: If I install 2 tomcat instances in the same machine, do they share the same JVM or each tomcat runs in its independent JVM?